# Unable to sync gradle, how to import old project to work on most up to date Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new to Android dev but basically I am trying to build a project but am unable to sync with gradle. I’ve spent hours trying different posts to solve this issue with no luck and would highly appreciate if someone can help me out. The source is this https://bitbucket.org/MaxPfeiffer/letyourbodymove/wiki/Home

Looks like it was last updated a while back and while I can download the apk and it works fine, I am unable to make any modifications to match my use case as I am unable to build it in android studio.

I have tried posts relating to fixing gradle sync issue but have been unsuccessful